# Can't run docker compose v2 in bash, having to use docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

The new docker compose v2 is supposed to allow to run `docker compose`, using the space to replace the dash, directly. But if I put it in a .sh file and run it, it can't recognize the command. But I can directly run `docker compose` from command line. Also if I replace `docker compose` with `docker-compose` in the script, it worked. So what am I missing, to make `docker compose` work in bash script?

Comment: Possibly the docker executable cannot be found from the script. Could be something with your path. Can you run docker --help from the script once to see if can be found? `docker-compose` is a python thing, that is installed to a completely different location.

Comment: What error do you get, exactly? You should edit your question to include it. Does it fail to find the `docker` executable? It would also be helpful to mention what your operating system you're using.

Comment: On host, `docker`, `docker compose`, `docker-compose` all works. In script, ```unknown shorthand flag: 'p' in -p
See 'docker --help'.

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND```

Comment: That's what I meant by 'not recognizing' it. The host OS is ubuntu 20.04, by the way.

Comment: And I copied the only line of script out and executed directly, it worked fine. I'm guessing the path inside script is somehow different from the bash, but have no idea how to verify or fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the probable reason of this is the bash file's EOL issue. The file was originally created on Windows and then copied to Linux.